# Custom Dynamic Grid

Tags: wpf, dynamic, grid

I am trying to display items in a grid however the rows and the columns should be generated dynamically. I actually implemented a custom control that derives from `Grid` control and provide additional properties such as `RowCount`.

Here is a picture of the grid generated by my custom control using two dimensinal string array as datasource:

[image]

But i think my control consumes more than needed resources because it simply destroys column and row definitions and recreates them. Is there any simpler way to implement that control?

Comment: post your code you tried so for..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom control to do that for you... you can use a standard `DataGrid`. There have been a number of questions on displaying dynamic data in a `DataGrid`. Please take a look at some of these posts:

[How do I bind a WPF DataGrid to a variable number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns)
[DataGridColumn Binding with Dynamically Generated Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036533/datagridcolumn-binding-with-dynamically-generated-data)
[Visualizing 2D Data in a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834749/visualizing-2d-data-in-a-table)
[Displaying multidimensional data in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679466/displaying-multidimensional-data-in-wpf/2690415#2690415)

Comment: Actually i need to because the custom grid should provide much more features such as headers on the left.

Comment: What? Do you mean like the `DataGrid.RowHeader`??? Take a look at the [DataGrid Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) *before* you dismiss it.